# How to save local settings of login form using Applicationdata class in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I designed two pages. One page consist of Login module and registration module using pivot control. Using sqlite database inserted values to data base. After login to the form when the user closes the application with out clicking logout on next app launch the same page should be redirected. The page page settings should be preserved and restored. I am trying to use Application data local settings in windows phone 8.1 apps but I cannot save the settings of the page.

```
 Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer data = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings; 
    public  void logout_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        data.Values["check"]=
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
```

I think the above code is wrong. But how to save the settings and use them. Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save the content of your page, you have to save the contents of your controls yourself. Right now you're saving the result of the naviagtion to another page, which is just a boolean.

To save the settings you can do this as soon as you leave the page:

```
Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["YourKeyHere"] = loginFormContent;
```

To restore the settings you can simply do the following:

```
string loginFormContent = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["YourKeyHere"];
```

Documentation that could be useful:

- [Documentation of the Frame.Navigate method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/apps/hh702396)
- [Documentation of LocalSettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localsettings.aspx)
- [Allowed typed in LocalSettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/apps/br205768.aspx)

Comment: where should I add the code to restore the settings. Weather in App.Xaml.cs or in main page. If App.Xaml.cs where to write code. If it in OnNavigetedto I caanot restore the settings. Please help me

Comment: I generally put it in OnNaviagtedTo. There you can just assign the restored values to the controls.

Comment: Please also solve this issue  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635367/about-application-datalocal-settings-and-sqlite-database-in-windows-phone-8-1