# About Application data(local settings) and Sqlite database in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sqlite, windows-phone-8.1

I have a small doubt about using SQLite database and local settings. I have an idea about how to use local settings for an app. When we use Application data(local settings) in our application we can restore the previous state of the application. Can we use sqlite local database to store and retrieve the values while we use local settings.

```
 protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {

        if (data.Values["check"] != null)
        {
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage1));
        }

      if (data.Values["add"] != null)
      {
          list_view.Items.Add(data.Values["add"].ToString());
      }

        if (data.Values["remove"] != null)
        {
            list_view.Items.Remove(data.Values["remove"]);
        }
        var dbpath = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path + "/Mydb1.db";
        var con = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbpath);

        await con.CreateTableAsync<list>();

    }


    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       if(!mypop.IsOpen)
       {
           mypop.IsOpen = true;
       }

    }

    public async void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dbpath = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path + "/Mydb1.db";
        var con = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbpath);


        list l = new list();
        data.Values["add"] = l.list1;
        l.list1 = text_input.Text.ToString();
        await con.InsertAsync(l);
        await con.UpdateAllAsync(l.list1);
        data.Values["add"] = l.list1;
        list_view.Items.Add(data.Values["add"].ToString());




      mypop.IsOpen = false;

    }


    private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(mypop.IsOpen)
        {
            mypop.IsOpen = false;
        }
    }

    private async void Button_Click_3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dbpath = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path + "/Mydb1.db";
        var con = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbpath);

        list l = new list();

        data.Values["remove"] = l.list1;

        l.list1 = list_view.SelectedItem.ToString();

        list_view.Items.Remove(list_view.SelectedItem);
        List<list> mylist = await con.QueryAsync<list>("delete from list where list1='" + list_view.SelectedItem + "'");
        mylist.Remove(l);
```

Please check and verify the code. I can only store single value to local settings. When I restart my application only one value will be shown. It wont show the values inserted in the listview. Please also check delete query. It is not working.. please help me...

Comment: are you familiar with how to use the debugger..? if so then step through the code that you have written.. once you pinpoint where the issue is happening then I think that it will help others to help you.. good luck and report back once you have effectively stepped through your code

Comment: Yaa I also tried using breakpoints but no exception raised. Please help me to restore the listview items when we restart the app. Now only one value of list item is displayed, but I need the whole items added to the listview...